# How to get back previous state in ReactJS Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onchange

I'm implementing a project where

- I have a array of `44` object data
- When I type `a` it returns `37` data immediately by `onChange()`
- After type `ad` it return `20`
- The **Problem** is when I return back to `a` by backspace. It stay on 20.
  How can I get back `37` data again.
- Code of `Root.jsx`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import icons from './services/icons'
import IconCard from './components/IconCard'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Search from './components/Search'


const icon = new icons()

class Root extends Component {

    state = {
        data: icon.getIcon(),
    }

    getBadge = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        const searched = this.state.data.filter(
            item => {
                if (e === '') {
                    return item
                } else if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase())) {
                    console.log(item)
                    return item
                }
            }
        )
        this.setState({ data:searched })
    }
    

    render() {
        const data = this.state.data

        return (
            <>
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <Search getBadge={this.getBadge} />
                </>
                <div className='container'>
                    <IconCard data={data} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Root
```

- state data be like

```js
state={
 data:data
}
```

- data

```json
{
    "title": "Academia",
    "hex": "41454A"
},
{
    "title": "Academia",
    "hex": "41454A"
}
```

- Code of `Search.jsx`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.props.getBadge(e.target.value)
    }

    render() {
        // console.log(this.state.search)
        return (
            <div className='container pb-3'>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3  align-self-center ">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search by brand..." onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understood your problem. You are mutating the original data whenever the search text is changing. Actually, you should not do that.

Instead,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import icons from './services/icons'
import IconCard from './components/IconCard'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Search from './components/Search'


const icon = new icons()

class Root extends Component {

    state = {
        data: icon.getIcon(),
        searchText: '',
    }

    getBadge = (search) => {
       console.log(search)
       return this.state.data.filter(
            item => {
              if (item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                    console.log(item)
                    return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
        )
    }
    

    render() {
        const data = this.state.data

        return (
            <>
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <Search 
                        value={this.state.searchText} 
                        onChange={(value) => this.setState({searchText: value})} />
                </>
                <div className='container'>
                    <IconCard data={this.getBatchData(this.state.searchText)} />
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Root
```

- Set searchText state in the component
- Change the props of the `<Search />` component
- Update the state when the search updates
- Update the `getBatchData()` as per above code.
- Everytime you update the search text, the data will remains same, but the filter will return the results according to search text

Answer (score -1):

In your function getBadge :

```
const searched = this.state.data.filter(...)
this.setState({ data:searched })
```

You are replacing the state with the object you found. So if the *data* object had 44 elements, after a search it will only have the filtered elements. All the other elements are gone.

You should consider filtering from a constant object instead of *state.data*

Comment: Wrong, there should not be any setState happened. If you are mutating the state, then it wont work

Comment: Yes, I took the problem differently from your answer. I imagined keeping the state.data to store the object found, and using another constant object (from the props for example) as the reference object (the one which won't be changed)